# Schema not working?

Tags: html, email, html-email, google-schemas

So I I have followed tutorials and I still can't get my Scehma to show up in the [Google tester](http://gmail-actions.appspot.com/)

```
<div itemscope itemtype="url">
        <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ViewAction">
            <link itemprop="target" href="http://www.blank.com/"/>
            <meta itemprop="name" content="What even is content?"/>
        </div>
        <meta itemprop="description" content="Description here"/>
    </div>
```

Obviuosly I have the rest of the email

Comment: it's very unclear what you're asking for. please try to be more precise and include as much information as possible

Comment: Were you able to get the action button to show?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="url">
```

with:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
```

You should get the following:

[image]

You can check out a microdata example on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action#view_action). I hope this helps.